# Store anchor text values on a set of two consecutive click events and return those values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a "question" list. Each li element has a set of "answers". I need to record the chosen anchor text values of the two valid consecutive pair of click events (question-answer pair). If the user clicks only on one or two questions but do not choose an answer I wont need to record the events.

the markup is something like this (I can't change it):

```
<ul class="question-list">
<li class="acordion">
    <a class="question">Q:Anchor Text</a>
    <div class="answer">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
      <h6><a>A:Anchor Text</a></h6>
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
      <h6><a>A:Anchor Text</a></h6>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="acordion">
    <a class="question">Q:Anchor Text</a>
    <div class="answer">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
      <h6><a>A:Anchor Text</a></h6>
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
      <h6><a>A:Anchor Text</a></h6>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I have:

```
  $('.question').on('click', function() {
  var questionAnchor = $(this).text();
  //I should be able to pass questionAnchor value to the next nested click event
      $('.answer a').on('click', function('{%=questionAnchor%}') {
      var question = questionAnchor;
      var answer = $(this).text();
      return question + " " + answer;
      });
  });
```

Or Should I "delegate":

```
$('.question').on("click", ".answer a", function() {
//Not sure how to store the two anchor values 
return question + " " + answer;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your event handling for the `.answer` is relative to the question. Something like this should do it.

```
$('.question').on('click', function () {
   var questionAnchor = $(this).text();
   $('.answer a').unbind('click');

   $(this).siblings('.answer').children('a').on('click', function () {
      var answer = $(this).text();
      console.log('Combo: '+ questionAnchor+' '+answer);
   });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the console is not displaying the log, however the first click event is logging into the console

Answer (score 0):

Please use delegation as tomorrow you might decide to bring the Q&A from server and have multiple Qs so it should work and unnecessary binding and unbinding just increases your coding effort. Stay simple and neat.

Added a button to validate you can validate on your own turf::)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.question-list').on("click", ".question, .answer a", function() {
  var that = $(this);
  if(that.hasClass('question'))
   that.closest('li.acordion').data({'question':that.text()});
  else that.closest('li.acordion').data({'answer':that.text()});
 });
});
function validate(){
 var result = [];
 $('.acordion').each(function(){
  if($(this).data('question') && $(this).data('answer')){
   result.push($(this).data('question') +' '+ $(this).data('answer'))
  }
 });
 console.log(result);
 //result is a array containing question answers only if question selected and answer selected
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="question-list">
<li class="acordion">
    <a class="question">Q:Anchor Text</a>
    <div class="answer">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
      <h6><a>A:Anchor Text</a></h6>
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
      <h6><a>A:Anchor Text</a></h6>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="acordion">
    <a class="question">Q:Anchor Text</a>
    <div class="answer">
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
      <h6><a>A:Anchor Text</a></h6>
      <h3></h3>
      <p></p>
      <h6><a>A:Anchor Text</a></h6>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type=button onclick="validate()" value="Check Q &amp; A"/>
```

Comment: I don't think delegation, while perhaps useful, is really relevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks joyBlanks, console logging (this).data('question/answer') array is returning 'Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined' before the validation.

Comment: @titico You need to type `$('li.acordian').eq(ind).data('question')` for the question where ind is the index of the Q&A section block starting from 0 and `~...data('answer')` for the answer choosen

Comment: @titico was this the answer??

Comment: @joyBlanks I suppose I need to have a .eq(CallFunctionHere) to make it work, right?. I will try to make it work if I can I will mark this one as the proper answer. Not sure how to use validate() without the button, I guess I can push the result inside the click event.